# When Notification is Clicked all other notification are also gone

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, android-notifications

I am Generating Notification using Firebase ,suppose there are 3 notification if user clicks on any one all the notification are gone ,here what i need is that when user clicks on one notification than the other 2 should be there in notification here is my code wt i have done.

```
    Intent intent;
        if (pref.getString("id","").equals("")){
             intent = new Intent(this, Login_Activity.class);
        }else {
             intent = new Intent(this, TicketListActivity.class);

        }
     //   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String channelId = "Default";

        String msgBody = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        String ticketid = remoteMessage.getData().get("ticket_Id");

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_launch)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body")).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body")))
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
//        manager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), notification);
        manager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

some info about `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`

> Flag indicating that this PendingIntent **can be used only once**. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int).
>
> If set, after send() is called on it, it will be automatically canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.

try to change this flag to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

also avoid this line

```
(int) System.currentTimeMillis()
```

`currentTimeMillis` is `long` so someday it may throw exception- yes, I know we have a lot of time until this moment, but still... use "real" id as `Integer` - for `PendingIntent` you may just put `0`, for `manager.notify` I would advise you to set some `int id = 0;` and increment it with every posted notification, so every next would have `id = prevNotificationId + 1` (use e.g. `SharedPreferences` for storing last used `id`)

Comment: Ok Sir @snachmsm

Comment: can we distinguish between the notification like in message body there is a id i need that id and open another activity is it possible?

Comment: add this id to `Bundle` of your `Intent`, like this `intent.putExtra("ticketid", ticketid);`. Inside `Activity` you can use `getIntent()` and next you can get access to this `Bundle` (commonly called `extras`)